# Show week numbers on datepicker starting from current week rather than start of year

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'd like to show the week numbers on a datepicker.  I curerently can show the numbers by using `showWeeks : true`

however these show the week numbers starting from the start of the year - I would like the week numbers to start from the current week.

I.e. Based on todays date of 29th June, week number 1 would be the week starting Monday 30th June rather than as it stands the week number is 27.

Any ideas how to maniupate this value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OPTION #1**

Get current week number as below([SOURCE](http://zerosixthree.se/snippets/get-week-of-the-year-with-jquery/))

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
    var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
    var today = new Date(this.getFullYear(),this.getMonth(),this.getDate());
    var dayOfYear = ((today - onejan + 86400000)/86400000);
    return Math.ceil(dayOfYear/7)
};

var today = new Date();
var currentWeekNumber = today.getWeek();
console.log(currentWeekNumber);
```

Using this, write another function which captures the element showing the week number and subtract the above result from it.

Use **onChangeMonthYear** ([SOURCE](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onChangeMonthYear)) method to fire the above method.

**OPTION #2**

Write your own **calculateWeek** method to show the appropriate week number. ([SOURCE](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-calculateWeek))

Comment: Perfect, makes sense.  Thanks for the logical answer!

Comment: Any pointers on where to go to iterate through the week numbers and make the calculations?

Comment: for the method "onChangeMonthYear", get each element which shows the week number and subtract your newly calculated week number. Keep in mind that you need to handle cases where the year is not same as the current one\

Comment: Cheers!  Came across the situation where the year is not the same as current one, but think Ive figured it out now - thank you

Comment: I tried a couple of days ago, but i dont have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what else you have in your date picker, you could create an array with the week numbers. Then link the date picker to it. This should give you fine control over the numbers and the ability to remove/replace etc

Comment: Thanks for the tip - could you please elaborate a little more on your answer?